# IMediaControl::Run followed by IMediaControl::Stop followed by IMeidaControl::Run doesn't switch on certain Onboard cameras

Tags: directshow, webcam

I have a DirectShow webcam application. I make use of Sample Grabber to get the buffer callbacks and IVideoWindow to control the display co-ordinates for the Preview. I have Preview and Capture Streams which I run as below.

g_pBuild->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video,cam,g_pGrabberF,pNullRenderer2); g_pBuild->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW, &MEDIATYPE_Video,cam,NULL,NULL);

On certain On board cameras, IMediaControl::Run followed by IMediaControl::Stop followed by IMediaCOntrol::Run doesn't switch on the camera.

Extenal USB cameras work properly here. How can I diagnose more on this? Any pointers, please help.

Comment: I know this is going to sound absurd, but I have observed repeatable problems with certain cameras (using certain drivers) when switching from run to stop to run very quickly. In one of your filters, try overriding Stop and, before calling the parent class's Stop, add Sleep(500), and see if that makes a difference. That (actually, Sleep(50)) consistently solved the problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its specific to a certain hardware issue in the unit.
Do a quick test by adding sleep of 1 sec between calls.
If it does help than you need to find a way to know when to unit state in idle or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important parts of the question which you did not provide:

1. Filter graph topologies
2. `HRESULT`s of the method calls

A problem you might be having is that one of the filters in the topology does not handle well state transitions and fails somewhere between states. Supposedly your second `Run` meets it still trying to complete `Stop`. You might get a `HRESULT` there which indicates the issue (better for you) or the filter fails silently.

The filter graph's is the unlikely source of the bug itself. Chances are high that it does everything flawlessly, however since internally it distributes the calls between filters, one of the filter is letting you down.